# Sum the digits of a strings using type(int)

Tags: python

I have seen this question when i googled but i tried something else to run this program which fails, help me to figure out why is my method wrong.

```
def sumDigits(s): 
      """Assumes s is string. If s is 'a2b3dc' it return 5""" 
      a=0
      for i in string: 
            if type(i) == int: 
                    a=a+1
      return a

sumDigits('ab23sdf');
```

This method return me zero. Why?

Comment: You should be getting a `NameError` because the local variable `string` is undefined. Also, you don't need a semicolon to end a Python statement.

Comment: use `a = a + int(i)`. then it will return 5

Comment: Do you want the *count* of digits (as your use of `a = a + 1` suggests, or the *sum*  of digits (as the name of your function implies)?

Comment: Have you thought about adding `print type(i)` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use isdigit instead.

```
i.isdigit()
```

When you iterate a string you get also a string, you need to check if given chararacter is a digit.

Secondly string variable is undefined, you should use s instead.

Answer (score 0):

`"2"` is still a string, not an integer:

```
>>> type("2")
<class 'str'>
>>> type(2)
<class 'int'>
```

Use `isdigit()` instead:

```
>>> "2".isdigit()
True
```

Then you need to convert the "digits" to actual integers before you can add them:

```
def sumdigits(s):
    return sum(int(c) for c in s if c.isdigit())
```

Answer (score 0):

First, string should be set as s. Next, the type is always going to be a string  with the above. Try useing ascii values instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(int(x) for x in 'ab23sdf' if x.isdigit())
```

output:

```
5
```

i am checking x is digit or not using `isdigit`, int(x) will convert x to integer. sum function will give you sum of the digit. Replace `int` with `float` if numbers are in fraction

Comment: You can remove the unnecessary list comprehension, and then your solution is identical to mine...:)

Comment: It would be better to add a note here that it would not work if the numbers were fractions `ab2.5sd0.5f` - this will give 12 and not 3.

Comment: if number is in fraction need to use float